# Change fixed header when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have little problem with my header. I am newbie in Bootstrap and I want change my header when I am scrolling down. Everything work's perfect. But when I reload page header is in "scrolling state". Sorry for my English. And Thanks.

You can try it on my web.

http://test.coleopterafarm.com/

My js:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {

var docElem = document.documentElement,
    header = document.querySelector( '.navbar-default' ),
    didScroll = false,
    changeHeaderOn = 300;

function init() {
    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
        if( !didScroll ) {
            didScroll = true;
            setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
        }
    }, false );
}

function scrollPage() {
    var sy = scrollY();
    if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
        classie.add( header, 'navbar-shrink' );
    }
    else {
        classie.remove( header, 'navbar-shrink' );
    }
    didScroll = false;
}

function scrollY() {
    return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
}

init();

})();
```

Comment: You have this code in your site:
`<script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
  $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
  });
});
        </script>`
you put it in your head tag where jQuery hasn't been loaded yet. put this script under the jQuery script.

this is not your issue, at least solve this before

Comment: This is not working. Header is still with background.

Comment: check the answer I gave, for me it works. if you put your document ready function after jQuery and add the line In the answer.

Comment: Perfect! Works. :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in your $(document).ready function:

`$(".navbar-shrink").removeClass("navbar-shrink");`